# Focussiert oder everybodys darling? / Focused or everybody's darling?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Ich schlage vor den `close`-Link nicht als persönliche Beleidigung oder gefährliche Waffe zu verstehen, sondern als Lupe, um das Thema der Seite fokussiert zu lassen auf "Deutsche Sprache und deren Anwendung".

[Hier ist eine Diskussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2312/266) die sich mit der Frage befasst, wieso man eine Pfandflasche, die leer ist, nicht verschließen soll. Mit deutscher Sprache hat das nichts zu tun - die dient lediglich als Aufhänger.

Sollen hier Kochrezepte, Wanderrouten und das Wetter diskutiert werden, wenn man irgendeinen wackligen Bezug als Alibi zur dt. Sprache herstellt?

Der close-Link ist keine Beleidigung oder Verletzung dessen, der die Frage gestellt hat. Im Gegenteil ist es viel netter eine Frage, die Off-topic ist, zu schließen, als abzuwerten, was sich auf die Reputation des Abgewerteten auswirkt.

Für Fragen, die Off-topic sind ist es das richtige Mittel - fürchtet Euch nicht es zu benutzen!

Aus Angst vor zu wenig Fragen sollten wir nicht die Qualität opfern. Wenn es eine solche Angst gibt sollte diese lieber separat in einem Metathread thematisiert werden.

---

I suggest not to understand the `close`-link as personal insult, but as a magnifying glass, in order to let the topic of the site remain focused on "german language and its usage".

[Here is a discussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2312/266) about why one shouldn't close an empty returnable bottle. It has nothing to do with german language - this is only the hook.

Should we discuss cooking recipes, hiking routes or the weather, if one can create some shaky relation to German language as alibi?

The close-link is not an insult or attack on the one who asked the question. On the contrary, it is nicer to close the question than to vote it down, which affects the reputation of the asker.

For questions which are off-topic this is the right means - don't be afraid to use it.

We should not sacrifice the quality in fear of those questions. If there is such a fear, we should better discuss it in a meta-thread.

Answer (score 5):

This discussion is old but I'd like to contribute.

The question is probably just badly written. If reworded properly, it'd be a language question.

The OP is not asking why do you need to close the bottle (if he is, just delete that part) but instead, if he got the translation right or not (leave this part).

It doesn't matter if he knows the translation or not. We're not supposed to ask things that we don't know, in fact, theoretically I could ask a question even if I knew the answer!

The problem is the wording, in my opinion, but appropriately corrected, it would work fine.

Comment: +1 rewording is mostly better than closing. In the *Pfandflaschen* example it may e.g. be one of the rare reasons we are able to translate a sentence but still do not transfer the meaning because of cultural differences. Then it would be a very nice topic on *finer points* of a language.

Comment: @Takkat Yeah. :)

Comment: I agree. As I understand him, his (correct) translation was meaningless to him, so he wanted to know if there is something in depth. He wrote: *Is there something I am not getting here*

Comment: @Em1 If you do, +1 it (it's more visible and it "counts" more); I appreciate the comment too, of course. :D

Comment: The headline of the question clearly states "What is the intention of this instruction..." and later "Is there something I am not getting here?" The answer is: Yes, there is something you're not getting here, which is the reason to keep it open. Towi gave the answer to that question, which in not about the language, but about fungi, developing in closed bottles. From the missing reaction of that user, I conclude his question was answered and he therefore didn't revisit again.

Comment: @userunknown We can tell the user that — by rewording — he'd manage to save it, and the answers will adjust by themselves.

Comment: I don't understand your reply. What do you want to say? I understand your answer only in a way, how to abuse the system to ask a question which is off topic. I'm not interested in outsmarting the system, I'm interested in sorting out which questions fit to the page, and which don't.

Comment: No-one talked about outsmarting anything. If he asks about a translation, it's on topic. Just remove the off topic content and it's a good question. You and the site don't lose anything if we can recover it, that's my opinion.

Comment: By the way, this is not my proposal: On every SE site, when a question can be saved, users and mods usually try to save it (sometimes successfully). It's better to recover a question than lose it. It adds content and it can be interesting for other users too.

Comment: If other users are interested in off-topic-questons too, and are attracted by leaving them open, then the page will get worse and worse. Imho the first step in answering a question is, to understand the intend of the person who made it. If I then discover it is off topic, I vote to close it, and don't try to make it artificically fit to our rules. People, who understood the original question in the best way will sit there with an invalid answer, which will be accepted from the person which asked, and edit wars with rollbacks have to be expected.

Answer (score 4):

Die Verwendung von "Beleidigung" und "gefährlicher Waffe" und "focussed" vs "everybody's darling" ist extrem tendenziös.

Wenn etwa ein ganzer Themenbereich, der mich interessiert, mit der Begründung "Fokus" systematisch geschlossen wird, dann braucht niemand die Widerrede als persönliche Befindlichkeit abzutun, und so zu tun, als ob es hier nur um die Schließung von Pfandflaschenthreads geht.

Wenn du konkrete Pfandflaschenthreads schließen willst, dann diskutiere diese Threads hier, aber verwende sie nicht als Argument dafür, dass Schließen von Threads im allgemeinen automatisch Qualitätszuwachs bedeutet, und dass das Ertragen von Interessen anderer, die dich nicht interessieren, etwas mit "everybody's darling" zu tun hat.

Anders gesagt: Wie wäre es damit, zuerst mal die Kritik zu fokussieren? (Auf konkrete Threads, und auf den Inhalt derselben statt auf das unterstellte Gefühlsleben der Autoren.)

The usage of "Beleidigung" and "gefährlicher Waffe" and "focussed" versus "everybody's darling" is extremely biassed.

For example, if a whole sub-subject that is interesting to me is systematically closed with justification "focus", then noone should discard my protests as personal emotions and pretend that the issue is one particular thread on bottles with deposits.

If you want to close a particular thread on bottles, then discuss these threads and their lack of merit here, but don't use them as justification that closure of threads automatically increases quality in general, and that tolerance of other people's interests that don't interest you, has anything to do with "everybody's darling".

Put succinctly: Why not first focus your critique? (On concrete threads and their content instead of the presumed emotional thoughts of their authors.)

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, welcher Themenbereich gemeint ist, den ich angeblich systematisch schließen will. Um welche Widerrede geht es? Ich sehe den Zusammenhang mit meinem Thread nicht. -- I don't understand which sub-subject is meant here. I guess it isn't reusable bottles. Where is your protest, you're refering to?

Comment: @userunknown: Du verstehst ja noch nicht einmal, warum hier keine Beleidigungen gewollt sind. Du zeigst hier nur wieder, dass Du nur für Deine eigenen Interessen lebst und nichts anderes zulässt. Das hat Phira deutlich gesagt. Nur Du bist nicht in der Lage, das zu verstehen. Oder willst es nicht, weil Du ja dann was an Dir ändern müßtest und in bereits so vielen Fällen so total daneben gelegen hättest. Selbsterkenntnis ist der beste Weg zur Besserung. Es wird Zeit ...

Answer (score 1):

Ich hätte im Fall der Pfandflaschen nicht für close gestimmt, werde aber auch nicht für reopen stimmen.

Andererseits wem hilft diese gewonnene Qualität. Ich sehe unser Problem nicht primär in der geringen Zahl von Fragen, sondern eher in der zu geringen Zahl aktiver Benutzer und der Visits ( http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage )

Solange hier off-topic Fragen beantwortet werden, bevor sie geschlossen werden, hilft es dem Fragesteller zu trotzdem.

Beachtet bitte, dass bei uns im FAQ steht

> for students having questions about German, expert speakers of German
>   wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation
>   questions from any language to German

im Gegensatz zum FAQ von English Language and Usage

> The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists,
>   etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. Questions on
>   the following topics are welcomed here

In Meinen Augen bedeutet Qulität eher, dass darauf geachtet wird, dass die Antworten richtig sind.

Wie ging es der Academie francaise mit ihrer ultagenialen Wortschöpfung 'Baladeur', das so bezeichnete Gerät ist heute nur noch Elektronikschrott.

Comment: Fragen zu beantworten, bevor sie geschlossen werden, verwässert einerseits den Fokus der Seite, und andererseits monopolisiert es Antwortgewinne auf den, der noch schnell vor dem Schließen geantwortet hat. Es erzieht auch nicht zur Disziplin sondern unterläuft gerade das, was mit dem Schließen beabsichtigt ist. -- To answer questions before closing is contraproductive. It monopolizes reputation gain and diffuses the focus of the site.

Comment: @userunknown: Wessen Fokus? Welchen Fokus? Ich sehe hier nur einen, der einen falschen Fokus hat ... Und was user unknown recht ist muß allen anderen billig sein? Träum weiter ...